# Update Postman stuck in loop

Tags: postman

I need to update from 4.9 to 4.9.1 because I do not have the following button in my settings
https://www.getpostman.com/docs/ignoring_ssl

I downloaded another version for my mac, when I click it, it brings me into 4.9, asks me to update, tells me I need to restart and stays in this loop, next time I open, it is in 4.9 and never updates to 4.9.1. Any ideas?